# Enlighten clicked slice on React-ChartJS-2 Pie Chart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am using React-ChartJS-2 to display a Pie Chart similar to code example bellow.

I would like to implement a onclick function to enlighten  (increase offset or put all other background colors to gray for example) a slice when I click on the associated legend label (which is the 'index' value in my code).

```js
export default function MyPieChart() {
    const chartOptions: ChartOption<'pie'> = {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                display: false,
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                onClick: function (e, legendItem) {
                    const index = legendItem.index as number;
                    const chart = this.chart;

                    /// Code Logic here

                    chart.update();
                },
            },
        },
    };

    const data = {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [15, 1, 1, 1, 45, 1],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                ],
                offset: 50,
            },
        ],
    };

    return <PieChart title={'My Chart'} data={data} options={chartOptions} />;
}
```

I have found working methods to hide a complete dataset ([example](https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/BWKKKo)), but in my case I only have one dataset, so I should work only with data in dataset[0]

Help would be appreciated !